# Correct way to containerize ASP.NET Core Web API Application

Tags: asp.net, docker, visual-studio, containers

I've written a minimal API using Visual Studio's 'ASP.NET Core Web API' project template. It's pretty simple and interfaces with an SQL Server db.

I want to containerize the application using Docker, so I can deploy the app to a cloud machine.

Currently, I'm using Visual Studio's 'Docker' build option (the green play button). When I build it this way it creates and runs the docker container and everything works as expected, the Swagger UI can be accessed using localhost:port. The problem is when I try to run the container without using Visual Studio (i.e. calling docker run manually), nothing functions as expected. I cannot access the Swagger UI or any other part of the app via localhost.

Note that this is while using (what I think is) the exact same docker run command that Visual Studio is using, as I copied the command from the visual studio 'Container Tools' output.

The command I'm using is

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\[User]\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\tools\TokenService.Proxy\linux-x64\net6.0:/TokenService.Proxy:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\tools\HotReloadProxy\linux-x64\net6.0:/HotReloadProxy:ro" -v "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\HotReload:/HotReloadAgent:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\source\repos\KPFIrmwareApiApp\KPFirmwareAPI:/app" -v "C:\Users\[User]\source\repos\KPFIrmwareApiApp:/src/" -v "C:\Users\[User]\.nuget\packages\:/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages:/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -P --name KPFirmwareAPI --entrypoint tail kpfirmwareapi:dev -f /dev/null
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think you might be missing configuring the port it uses. Something like -p 80:80 (external port:internal port)

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but using docker inspect on the container shows that they are indeed configured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running in Visual Studio (especially in the Debug configuration) it  does a lot of optimalizations to speed up debugging. You can read about them in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2022#dockerfile-builds-in-visual-studio)

For your particular case you'll want to simplify to:
`docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/home/app/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/home/app/.aspnet/https:ro" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -P --name KPFirmwareAPI kpfirmwareapi`

The volumes and enviorment variables i left in the command allow you to take advantage of the certifcate the tools made for you for local testing. If you don't need SSL you can remove those.

Note: You'll also need to build the full image (kpfirmwareapi:dev is for debugging only) which you can do in VS by right clicking on the Dockerfile and selecting "Build Docker Image":
[image: Dockerfile->Build Docker Image]